# Get Namespace Name in Root Element via PHP SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, namespaces, simplexml, xml-namespaces

Assume I have the following XML (this is the standard for ATOM)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">

    <title>Example Feed</title>
    <subtitle>A subtitle.</subtitle>
    <link href="http://example.org/feed/" rel="self" />
    <link href="http://example.org/" />
    <id>urn:uuid:60a76c80-d399-11d9-b91C-0003939e0af6</id>
    <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>


    <entry>
        <title>Atom-Powered Robots Run Amok</title>
        <link href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03" />
        <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03.html"/>
        <link rel="edit" href="http://example.org/2003/12/13/atom03/edit"/>
        <id>urn:uuid:1225c695-cfb8-4ebb-aaaa-80da344efa6a</id>
        <updated>2003-12-13T18:30:02Z</updated>
        <summary>Some text.</summary>
        <content type="xhtml">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                <p>This is the entry content.</p>
            </div>
        </content>
        <author>
            <name>John Doe</name>
            <email>johndoe@example.com</email>
        </author>
    </entry>

</feed>
```

Also, assume that the above XML is in a webpage whose address is `http://www.example.com/atom.xml`

I konw you can get the root element name via the follwoing code:

```
// Using curl to access the page
$ch = curl_init('http://www.example.com/atom.xml');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$xml = new SimpleXmlElement($result);
$root = $xml->getName();
echo ($root)  // This prints "feed", which is the root element
```

Also, I know that the following call will get all the root namespaces.

```
$xml->getNamespaces(true)
```

In our case, the return value is:

```
Array
(
    [] => http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom
)
```

However, I really like to know the name of the namespace. In other words, I do not know which function to call that returs **xmlns**. How do I know the name of the namespace? I need it to make some verifications before processing.

Please help, and thanks.

Comment: You're are mistaken, the alias/prefix used for a namespace is not relevant. If you validate it, the validation is broken. The namespace is `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` or for the `div` nodes in `content` it is `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"However, I really like to know the name of the namespace. In other words, I do not know which function to call that returs **xmlns**"*.

`xmlns` is XML syntax for default attribute name for namespace declaration. It isn't clear what you're trying to verify, but I think it is safe to assume that if `getNamespaces()` returns namespace which prefix is empty then the source XML has a valid default namespace (in other words, the source XML has **xmlns**).

Quoting from W3C "[Namespaces in XML](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114)" for easy reference :

1. > If the attribute name matches `DefaultAttName`, then the namespace name in the attribute value is that of the default namespace in the scope of the element to which the declaration is attached. In such a default declaration, the attribute value may be empty. Default namespaces and overriding of declarations are discussed in "5. Applying Namespaces to Elements and Attributes". 
   >   [[Default Namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#dt-defaultNS)]
2. > [3]     `DefaultAttName`    ::=     'xmlns' .
   >   [[Default Attribute Name](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-19990114/#NT-DefaultAttName)]

Comment: I had a misunderstading about xmlns, your answer helped a lot. Thanks.